# Bean both an EJB and JX-RS resource

Tags: java, rest, ejb, jax-rs, ejb-3.0

In terms of objects created at run time by the application server, what is the difference between

- making of a bean both an EJB and a JAX-RS resource

  @Stateless
  @Local
  @Path("current")
  public class Facade
  {

  @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

  @EJB
    ...

  // methods
  }
- using two different beans

  @Path("current")
  public class Facade
  {
     @EJB
     private MyEjb myEjb;

  // methods
  }

  @Stateless
  @Local
  public class MyEJB
  {
   // methods
  }

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT:

ahah maybe my real questions would be about what's the result of using jax-rs annotations on an EJB, but that' basically the same question I asked.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have a question in the back of your head for which you are collecting data, try asking that question instead. This is just too vague to answer without context.

Answer (score 2):

It works. But if we stick to Oracle specification, exposing an EJB as a Web Service (rest or soap) is a kind of quick solution, with you promising to revisit this approach in the nearest future :-)

Infact, again sticking to what Oracle say, the EJB should reside on the business layer, and the web service should be in the integration layer.

I am not arguing that exposing an EJB is a wrong approach, but just because it is quite easy to develop rest service in Java, I would create a façade class, and transform in a service. Then I would inject the EJB into the class, or by jndi lookup if it is a rest. To have better separation of concerns.

This way you don't end up with a single class stuffed with annotation, but you are introducing flexibility, and have an architecture that may evolve, for example maybe you can decide in the future to deploy the business layer on a dedicated machine...whatever.

Comment: I don't quite understand from the above why an EJB should not implement and expose a REST API while being in the "integration tier".  Security and Transactional semantics could be set easily with an EJB and after all, which is the better alternative given the standard EE tools, a servlet implementation?

Comment: The better alternative is to have a class acting as a web service only, wich delegate its business operations to an ejb